# facebook connect error

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am getting error but empty statusText, here is my code

```
 var ajaxUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + accessToken
                        $.ajax({
                          url: ajaxUrl,
                          dataType: 'json',                       
                          success: function(user){
                            alert('h');
                          },
                          error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            alert(xhr.statusText);
                          }
                        });
```

Comment: you got a [cross-domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax), your code should read:

```
var ajaxUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + accessToken
                        $.ajax({
                          url: ajaxUrl,
                          dataType: 'json',                       
                          success: function(user){
                            alert('h');
                          },
                          error: function(xhr, statusText, thrownError){
                            alert(statusText);
                          }
                        });
```

That is to say, you have your `error` function defined incorrectly.

In addition, you cannot make a AJAX call for JSON from a domain name that is not the one from which the current page came... you need to use [JSONP](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) for that

Comment: statusText is 'error'. I am not sure why its executing error: callback. Is there any problem in the code? Why I am not getting success: callback?

Comment: Although if I directly enter the url https://gra..... with accessToken it gives me correct data. But not working with ajax call, any idea?

Comment: I got the same issue right now. Any idea? Is not a cross domain issue 'cause I'm in a phonegap app.